# Lazy Reads in Castle.ActiveRecord

Tags: castle-activerecord, database

I am writting an application which needs to periodically (each week for example) loop through several million records ina  database and execute code on the results of each row.

Since the table is so big, I suspect that when I call SomeObject.FindAll() it is reading all 1.4million rows and trying to return all the rows in a SomeObject[].

Is there a way I can execute a SomeObject.FindAll() expression, but load the values in a more DBMS friendly way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with `FindAll()` - which, as you've surmised, will try to load all the instances of the specified type at one time (and, depending on how you've got NHibernate set up may issue a stupendous number of SQL queries to do it).

Lazy loading works only on properties of objects, so for example if you had a persisted type `SomeObjectContainer` which had as a property a list of `SomeObject` mapped in such a way that it should match all `SomeObject`s and with `lazy="true"`, then did a `foreach` on that list property, you'd get what you want, sort-of; by default, NHibernate would issue a query for each element in the list, loading only one at a time. Of course, the read cache would grow ginormous, so you'd probably need to flush a lot.

What you can do is issue an HQL (or even embedded SQL) query to retrieve all the IDs for all SomeObjects and then loop through the IDs one at a time fetching the relevant object with FindByPrimaryKey. Again, it's not particularly elegant.

To be honest, in a situation like that I'd probably turn this into a scheduled maintenance job in a stored proc - unless you really have to run *code* on the object rather than manipulate the data somehow. It might annoy object purists, but sometimes a stored proc is the right way to go, especially in this kind of batch job scenario.